# Transaction has been reverted by the EVM:

Tags: web3js, metamask

I have created a contract and contract is successfully deployed. I can see it on 'https://rinkeby.etherscan.io/' 
While accessing its ABI using web3
and paying money using meta mask

Smart contract code is

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.17;

contract mypool{
    address public manager;
    string poolname;
    uint256 poolEndDate;
    uint256 poolAmount;

    constructor () public {
        manager = msg.sender;
    }

    struct Payer {
        string name;
        address player;
        uint256 amount;
    }

    Payer[] public players;

    function enterPoolInfo(string name,uint256 endDate, uint256 amount) public {
        poolname = name;
        poolEndDate = endDate;
        poolAmount = amount;
    }

    function enter(string name,uint256 amount) public payable {
        require(msg.value > .01 ether);

        Payer memory m;
        // players.push(Payer{player:msg.sender,amount:amount});
        m.player = msg.sender;
        m.amount = amount;
        m.name = name;
        players.push(m);
    }

}
```

I got the following error

```
index.js:368 Uncaught (in promise) Error: Transaction has been reverted by the EVM:
{
  "blockHash": "0x9695b98f4e55b98103bb1282dfffbcbddac03002b1199789ea0f027b1baee09f",
  "blockNumber": 2775473,
  "contractAddress": null,
  "cumulativeGasUsed": 1755656,
  "from": "0xdc091bc86e95ae492cdd67abf051e7c7e3432d70",
  "gasUsed": 24017,
  "logsBloom": "0x00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000",
  "status": false,
  "to": "0xe0ef5f6d4b4f75f66bb96713c17549c1ded4af98",
  "transactionHash": "0xaed58f7d6c230f41b30c2d6f45e057e4d63188fa1542540767ee90aa9f567ba8",
  "transactionIndex": 18,
  "events": {}
}
```

Comment: What is the code for the contract?

Comment: I have edit my post, Please check

Answer (score 5):

The problem here is the amount of Ether you are sending as a part of your request.

In your code you have the following line:

```
require(msg.value > .01 ether);
```

This means you must send a minimum of `.01 ETH` to the contract, or it will `revert` like you are seeing.

Taking you transaction hash, and looking up the transaction on Etherscan:

https://rinkeby.etherscan.io/tx/0xaed58f7d6c230f41b30c2d6f45e057e4d63188fa1542540767ee90aa9f567ba8

We can see that you are only sending `100 wei` to the contract when calling the function. You simply need to increase this to `.01 ETH`, and it should get past the `revert` error.

Comment: if i send more than one either , I am getting same error

Comment: You are calling the `enter()` function right? Can you show me a transaction where you send more than 1 ETH? I do not see any such transactions [here](https://rinkeby.etherscan.io/address/0xe0ef5f6d4b4f75f66bb96713c17549c1ded4af98).

Comment: https://rinkeby.etherscan.io/address/0xF2836AA48f2DFF4fc21ab69071d415B1d471236C

plese check

Comment: Increase your gas limit in this case. You can see your "gas limit" was `30000` and the "gas used by txn" was `30000`, which means it ran out of gas before it could complete the operation. Gas limit should be above the gas used by the transaction, and any additional gas will be returned to the `msg.sender`.